# (Javascript) Need help converting an object to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object which has objects inside in it at the following form:

```
Object { 
       "item1": { "subitem1": 5, "subitem2": 10 },
       "item2": { "subitem1": 3, "subitem2": 12, "subitem3": 1 },
       "item3": { "subitem1": 8, "subitem2": 1, "subitem3": 3 }
       }
```

I want to convert it to an array with the following form:

```
[0] Object { key: "item1", "subitem1": 5, "subitem2": 10 }
[1] Object { key: "item2", "subitem1": 3, "subitem2": 12, "subitem3": 1 }
[2] Object { key: "item3", "subitem1": 8, "subitem2": 1, "subitem3": 3 }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: The order in which you get keys/values of an object is not guaranteed so you can't convert the object to an array where the first element happens to be `item1`, at least not according to the specifications. The answers may work by accident but can break at any moment if implementation of JS interpreter changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the entries of the object and assign the key.

```js
var object = { item1: { subitem1: 5, subitem2: 10 }, item2: { subitem1: 3, subitem2: 12, subitem3: 1 }, item3: { subitem1: 8, subitem2: 1, subitem3: 3 } },
    result = Object.entries(object).map(([key, o]) => Object.assign({ key }, o));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Order of keys/values/entries `for ... in` or `for ... of` in object is not guaranteed, you can't depend on the resulting array to be in any particular order.

Comment: @HMR, actually, yes it follows some rules, like integer, which could be indices for an array are sorted first and then all keys are sorted by insertation order.

Comment: The point was that you should warn about this since the specification says [arbitrary order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Deleted_added_or_modified_properties). It happens to get the key/values/entries in the order that they are added/specified but there is no guarantee. If order is important then another data type should be chosen or the resulting array should be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const obj = { "item1": { "subitem1": 5, "subitem2": 10 }, "item2": { "subitem1": 3, "subitem2": 12, "subitem3": 1 }, "item3": { "subitem1": 8, "subitem2": 1, "subitem3": 3 }},
res = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({key, ...obj[key]}));

console.log(res);
```

Do note, however, the order of the keys retrieved from `Object.keys` is not guaranteed to be the same order as listed in your object

Comment: Order of keys in object is not guaranteed, you can't depend on the resulting array to be in any particular order.

Comment: Would also advice using `forEach` if you are mutating something. The `map` function is usually used with pure callback function.

Comment: @HMR okay, I change it to be a pure callback now

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this mate**

```js
let obj = { "item1": { "subitem1": 5, "subitem2": 10 }, "item2": { "subitem1": 3, "subitem2": 12, "subitem3": 1 }, "item3": { "subitem1": 8, "subitem2": 1, "subitem3": 3 } };

let op =[];
for(let key in obj){
  op.push({
    key : key,
    ...obj[key]
  })
}
console.log(op);
```